# Extend a Class in C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core application, an WebAPI Controller, sending me a JSON array of `Record` objects:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Record")]
public class RecordController : Controller
{   
    // GET: api/Record
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<Record>> Get()
    {
        var records = await repository.GetListAsync<Record>();
        //foreach (var record in records) {
        //    record.IsNew = checkIfNew(record);
        //}
        return records;
    }
```

I display the `Record` list in a array, via an AngularJS on the client side.

A new demand was to highlight the records that are new for a user. So I need to calculate add an extra boolean "IsNew" to my list of records.

How could I extend the `Record` just for that function and add to the sent JSON my calculated "IsNew" boolean, without modifying the initial `Record` class?

Comment: Please read [ask] and share your research. Extending a class is thoroughly documented. You're encountering problems because you're using entity models as DTOs. Introduce a new DTO and map your entities to that DTO.

Comment: I don't use any Entity models. I don't use the EntityFramework at all

Comment: I'm not saying you use Entity Framework. Did you understand the rest of my comment?

Comment: Your other question does not fit my needs. I need to add a new boolean to each record of my list... the proposed solution encapsulates the Record to "Data", then adds a "IsNew", is not what I want... actually will have a list and a "IsNew", I don't need that... I need Record(x).IsNew

Comment: There are two answers in the duplicate, each proposing another approach. Either will work. There are many other potential duplicates. Like I said, search before asking a question, and include that research in your question.

Comment: The other answer is not maintenable. Each time Record changes I should not forget updating the new object, and also I need to do a clone constructor... not good

Comment: any of approaches in the "duplicate" question does not *extend* a class...

Comment: Because you cannot meaningfully extend a class to do what you want. Your repository is returning an Animal class and you want a Cow. You can't do that. You'll have to either create a copy constructor, or map all properties onto the derived class.

Comment: @Serge The duplicate gives you exactly the answer you need. Either inherit and add your properties (which as pointed out by CC) has it's own problems, or use AutoMapper, which will warn you about missing properties if you do it properly.

Comment: @DavidG, I just explained above why the "duplicated" answers doesn't feet my need. I still searching a workaround.

Comment: I don't need a wrapper, cause this will break my client logic. I don't need to inherit, cause I should create a deep clone constructor and it's not easy/maintainable, I just need to add a property to existing class and fill it, then send JSON only for that function!

Comment: @Serge No, you're not listening. Go take a look at AutoMapper, it will do everything you need.

Comment: @DavidG, AutoMapper, I have no ADO.NET nor EF... Will it work for my case?

Comment: Yes it will, please go and look for yourself...

Comment: @DavidG, it seems to work. Thanks. It wasn't however a solution proposed by the "duplicate" thread... Hope do not have bad surprises of performance or loss of data... :) thank you!

Comment: The second answer in the duplicate suggests to use AutoMapper, I suggest you look harder next time!

Comment: @DavidG I should confess, when I saw the guy cloning all the properties into a new object, I did't read till the last line of the answer...

Answer (score 0):

From my experience its far better to extend an existing object and make it wider than to start creating a lot of extra types to represent specific instances. If you have control of the "Record" class then just put a new property on it called "IsNew" and set it to true in this action.

If you don't want to do that then you have to do things like:

1) Creating a new class with the extra property

2) Mapping all of the properties from one to the other

3) Changing the return type from "Record" to something like "NewRecord"

All of this is a bad idea.

Comment: And in my experience it is a bad idea to inherit from entity classes, especially when crossing domain boundaries. Your entity classes contain properties you don't want to expose, probably even circular references which prevent them from being serialized, tie your API to your database schema and, as you already explain, have to be mapped to and from your extended class, because the data source (Entity Framework DbContext, or repository as in the question) returns the base class, not the derived one. If you start mapping anyway, map to and from a separate domain object or DTO. Don't inherit.

Comment: I think it it's a good idea to have separate *UI models*. I would create a separate model and use an *assembler* to translate your *entity model* to a *UI model*.

Comment: my Record properties are linked to a (Azure) DataTable. If I add a new Property it will add a new property to the DataTable. But the property is not a pertinent one, I don't need nor want to store that property in the "DB"

Comment: More than that, the "New" property is not specific to a Record, is specific to a User, so there is any meaning to add to the Business object Record a property specific to the User or the GUI...

Comment: In this case I think I would have to agree with the other comments and suggest that you add a UI model that is specific for this controller action.